# Using Count and Case to determine number of instances text appears

Tags: sql, count, case

I'm trying to get my head around COUNT CASE statements, so for my example I have a table with the field 'Salutation', and contains data like 'Dear Mr Smith' and 'Dear Mrs Bloggs'.

```
SALUTATION
Dear Mr Smith
Dear Mrs Bloggs
Dear Mr Jefferson
Dear Prof Jenkins
Dear Mr Klein
Dear Mr Smith
```

I want to find out how many instances of 'Mr' we have in the table, and have tried the following:

```
select 
count(case when salutation like 'Dear Mr %' then 1 else 0 end) as "CountColumn"
from CLIENTS
GROUP BY salutation
```

I was expecting to get a result like this:

```
CountColumn
3
```

Instead I get:

```
CountColumn   
2
1
1
1
1
```

It is counting each instance of 'Dear Mr Smith' instead of just 'Dear Mr'. I am having trouble figuring out how to achieve this, I thought the group by clause would group all the results together?

Comment: case _expression_, not statement.

Comment: You may want to use a window function to count over the whole group. Or, if you don't need any other information, just remove the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: And you don't want a `COUNT()`, you want a `SUM()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Count will treat any value as a countable value, so 1 & 0 will both be treated the same.  NULL is not a countable value and can be used in place of your 0 to not count that record.

Grouping on Salutation will reset your count for every distinct Salutation.  You have Dear Mr Smith twice, all other records only show up once, which is what you ended up with in the observed results.

Based on your desired results, it seems like you want a count of the distinct salutations starting with Dear Mr.

```
select count(distinct salutation)
from CLIENTS
where salutation like 'Dear Mr %'
```

Comment: Ahh it was the 0 still being counted the same as 1 that was causing me problems. The following worked as I was expecting:

`'SELECT count (case when salutation like ('Dear Mr %') then 1 else null end) as MrCount
,count (case when salutation like ('Dear Mrs %') then 1 else null end) as MrsCount
from CLIENTS'`

Comment: @Dekks - That's only half the problem you experienced.  You rightly point out that `COUNT(0)` gives the same results as `COUNT(1)`, but this answer also deals with the fact that `Mr Smith` is in your data twice.

Comment: But why not count 'Dear Mr Smith' twice if it's in the data? The OP didn't originally specify counting distinct values. Also, while this does give the correct result, it doesn't address how to properly use a `CASE` to get a count of specific values.

Comment: @Shawn The OP was expecting to get 3 results.  Based on the data provided, that is only possible if Mr Smith is only counted once.

Comment: @WesH I misread the intent since the title was "Using Count and Case to determine number of instances text appears". I figured the 3 results was an incorrect count since the OP never explicitly said he wanted to get rid of the duplicates. I think the original question could use some clearing up, since that does seem to be what's wanted.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just use this.

```
select 
count(distinct salutation) as "CountColumn"
from CLIENTS
where salutation like 'Dear Mr %'
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8729d/2)

Comment: This will return 4 count, as mr smith is repeated twice , the output should return `distinct count `

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve this  way

```
select count( Distinct salutation)  from @table where  SALUTATION like 'Dear Mr %'
```

Sample data

```
declare @table table (
SALUTATION varchar(255))
insert into @table( SALUTATION)
select 'Dear Mr Smith'
union all
select 'Dear Mrs Bloggs'
union all
select 'Dear Mr Jefferson'
union all
select 'Dear Prof Jenkins'
union all
select 'Dear Mr Klein'
union all
select 'Dear Mr Smith'
```

Use sub query

```
select count(*) Countcolumn
from 
(
select distinct * from @table where  SALUTATION like 'Dear Mr %'
) x
```

Comment: Use of Select * in the inner query may return additional records per salutation instead of the distinct salutation values.  This would be better written as select distinct salutation

Comment: @WesH Not for the example given inside this answer.  I agree it would be an improvement, a generalisation, but given that the answer specifies a table with a single column, it's a pretty narrow criticism.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this because you're using the GROUP BY statement, then the query are returning how much 'Dear Mr %'s you have for everyone of the cases.
2 'Dear Mr Smith'
1 'Dear Mr Jefferson
etc...
If you want to get the total ammount of 'Dear Mr %' registers you have, only have to remove the GROUP BY statement.

The query will be like:

```
select 
count(case when salutation like 'Dear Mr %' then 1 end) as "CountColumn"
from CLIENTS
```

And if you don't want to have in consideration the repeated registers...

```
select 
count(case when C.salutation like 'Dear Mr %' then 1 end) as "CountColumn"
from (select distinct salutation from CLIENTS) C
```

Comment: Counting 0 would still increment the counter by 1. Replace count by sum in your SQL and that would be a valid answer ;-)

Comment: `COUNT(0)` gives the same result as `COUNT(1)`.  You either want `SUM()` or to replace `0` with `NULL`.

Comment: Totally agree, was a mistake copy-pasting the code of the post, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're getting multiple results because you're grouping by salutation. Anytime the salutation is different, it's creating a new group and counting the results for that group.

Also, you want to use sum with Case When instead of Count, because Count treats any results as a 1 and sums all. Switching to Sum(Case When) will result in:

```
select 
sum(case when salutation like 'Dear Mr %' then 1 else 0 end) as CountColumn
from CLIENTS
GROUP BY salutation
```

will result in:

```
CountColumn
2
0
1
0
1
```

To get closer to the desired result you could use a subquery of this and sum the CountColumn results.

```
select sum(CountColumn) as CountColumn
from
(
    select 
    sum(case when salutation like 'Dear Mr %' then 1 else 0 end) as CountColumn
    from CLIENTS
    GROUP BY salutation
) a
```

but this will sum up all the examples of 'Dear Mr %' and will count Dear Mr Smith twice. The result will be

```
CountColumn
4
```

If you're hoping for each unique instance of 'Dear Mr %', you could convert all results from the inner query to 1 when they are nonzero.

```
select sum(case when CountColumn>0 then 1 else 0 end) as CountColumn
from
(
    select 
    sum(case when salutation like 'Dear Mr %' then 1 else 0 end) as CountColumn
    from CLIENTS
    GROUP BY salutation
) a
```

While I was writing this the answer I would recommend was posted by @user9331264 and @WesH, remove all examples in your Where expression and count the unique results.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you're looking to do with a simple `SUM()` or with a subquery and a window function if you need other columns.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b6a61/1)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t (SALUTATION varchar(100), SomethingElse int) ;
INSERT INTO t (SALUTATION, SomethingElse)
VALUES 
    ('Dear Mr Smith', 1)
  , ('Dear Mrs Bloggs', 1)
  , ('Dear Mr Jefferson', 3)
  , ('Dear Prof Jenkins', 4)
  , ('Dear Mr Klein', 2)
  , ('Dear Mr Smith', 1)
;
```

**Simple Sum()**:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(CASE WHEN SALUTATION LIKE 'Dear Mr %' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as CountColumn
FROM t
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b6a61/1/0)**:

```
| CountColumn |
|-------------|
|           4 |
```

**Subquery and Window Function**:

```
/* If SELECTing another column */
SELECT s1.SomethingElse
  , sum(s1.SalCount) OVER () AS CountColumn
FROM (
    SELECT t.SomethingElse
      , (CASE WHEN t.SALUTATION LIKE 'Dear Mr %' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as SalCount
    FROM t
) s1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b6a61/1/1)**:

```
| SomethingElse | CountColumn |
|---------------|-------------|
|             1 |           4 |
|             1 |           4 |
|             3 |           4 |
|             4 |           4 |
|             2 |           4 |
|             1 |           4 |
```